# Paper by Diestel, Faires and Huff

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebras, paper-request

I have been looking for a (long) while for the following paper:

**J. Diestel, B. Faires, and R. Huff, *Convergence and boundedness of measures on non-sigma complete algebras*, preprint, 1976.**

This preprint is cited frequently in papers on convergence and boundedness of sequences of measures on Boolean algebras, especially in the older ones, but it seems that it hasn't been published anywhere. I suspect that the results from the paper are now spread among other (authors') papers, so everything is known to me, but I would like to look personaly into the very preprint.

**Does anyone possess a copy of this preprint?**

Comment: Why don't you email Barbara?  You can get her email address by Googling her.

Comment: The simplest solution is always the hardest... Thanks, Bill, I've just mailed her, I hope she checks sometimes her mailbox. The other two authors have already passed away. Anyway, if someone has an access to the preprint, please tell me!

Comment: I asked Barbara, she immediately answered that she would look for the paper, but it's 2 now weeks of silence from her side, so I guess I should look somewhere else...